# Clipboard content availability in Qt after application shuts down

Tags: qt

ALL,

Looking at the documentation for Qt [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html), I don't see a special method for saving the clipboard content after the application shuts down/exits.

Am I missing something or is it done automatically (data preservance on the application exit)?

TIA!

Comment: I suspect it depends from operating system and content type, due to how the system clipboard works internally. On Linux if you don't have a clipboard manager only text will persist; on Win32 it should persist some well-known types. Application-specific data (which requires a round-trip through your application) won't probably ever persist.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, on Windows you need to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ole2/nf-ole2-oleflushclipboard in order to preserve the Clipboard content on shutdown. On GTK you need to use https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-store to do the same. And I'm sure there is something similar for OSX NSPasteboard. So it is not dependant on the data type, but rather on the API call.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to achieve something of the following items:

1. When application shuts down or exits, save something to the clipboard.
2. In case application shuts down or exits and if there is something in clipboard stored, you want this content not to be gone.

I will start from the second point, since it is the easiest to explain. Data associated with the [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html) is not bound to the [QApplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) scope. In other words, you can imagine that [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html) is just an API allowing to get data from OS clipboard, and to set it (it is similar to [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) in a way that [QThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) is just a way to represent actual thread, but is not a thread by itself). So, if you will set something through [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html), then despite the app shuts down, no data will be gone. So, setters of class [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html) just set the data, but takes no ownership of managing its' scope.

Now, if you want to set some data to clipboard in case your app exists or shuts down, you could probably connect to [QObject::destroyed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal, and in its' handler to set something. For instance, you can do something like that:

```
QObject::connect(&app, &QObject::destroyed, []
{
    QApplication::clipboard()->setText("Something you would like to set.");
});
```

Not sure why would you want to do that given the fact that Qt does not control operating system's clipboard data scope in any way, but I show this example, since it is a possibility.

Comment: you understanding is correct - I am looking for #2. So basically IIUC, I don't need to do anything, as the data stored on the clipboard will not go anywhere on application exit, as an application doesn't own the clipboard. That you - this simplifies my logic a bit.